# TCPDF Align Left Center Right in single line

Tags: php, tcpdf

I want to create a footer for a PDF document that contains the date left aligned, the creator centered and the page right aligned. These should be in a single line. I tried the following code:

```
$this->Cell(0, 10, $date->format('d.m.Y'), 0, false, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
$this->Cell(0, 10, 'Creator', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
$this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
```

The creator is shifted to the right and overlays with the pages:

[image: PDF Document Footer]

Does anybody have a solution for that problem?

Comment: The code looks right to me according to the docs: http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a33b265e5eb3e4d1d4fedfe29f8166f31. What happens if you comment out the page number line?

Comment: oh, forgot to mention that! then the creator is also on the right.

Comment: If you can provide a bigger code sample, I can try to set it up locally to see if I get the same results. What happens if you make the first cell centered? Is this the latest version of TCPDF?

Comment: that is actually the whole code except the `$this->SetY(-15);` before these three lines. They are located in the overriding `Header()` method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the width of the `Cell()`, as according to the docs http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a33b265e5eb3e4d1d4fedfe29f8166f31 your `$date->format('d.m.Y')` `Cell()` is extending to the right margin, forcing the other cells on the line to the right margin.

> $w    (float) Cell width. If 0, the cell extends up to the right margin.

Try something like (may have to adjust based on font size)

```
$this->Cell(20, 10, $date->format('d.m.Y'), 0, false, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');   
$this->Cell(20, 10, 'Creator', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M'); 
$this->Cell(20, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
```

Answer (score 7):

I ran into alignment issue with TCPDF too. I noticed that if you use x-coordinate as 0, then it will use the attribute 'R' for right alignment. But if it's set to a non zero value then it ignores the 'R' setting. Here's the statement I used for right alignment.

```
$this->Cell(0, 9, 'Text-to-be-aligned-right', 0, false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M' );
```

Comment: Thanks :) needed this too!